# How can I call a method after page transition from component outside of router-view?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vue-router

I want to call a method after page transition from a **ChildComponent.vue** which is a child of **App.vue**.
I'm using VueRouter to re-render content inside `<router-view>`.

The problem is that **ChildComponent.vue** is not inside `<router-view>` thus it is not re-created on route change.

The best solution I've got is that inside of the **ChildComponent.vue** I'm watching a `$route` which is triggering a function. The problem with that solution is that, the route change automatically when `<router-link>` is clicked and after that `<router-view>` animation is triggered and content is replaced. I know that I could resolve it by using a setTimeout but it then relays strictly on the length of my animation and probably is a bad practice.

Because it is triggering on the route change (before content is changed) I cannot access any of the content that will appear on the next page.

**APP COMPONENT**

```
<template>
    <ChildComponent />
    <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
            <component :is="Component"/>
        </transition>
    </router-view>
</template>

<script>
import { ChildComponent } from "./components";
export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
        ChildComponent ,
    },
};
</script>
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
<template>
    <div>Child component</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.test();
    },

    watch: {
        '$route'(to, from) {
            this.test()
        }
    },

    methods: {
        test(){
            console.log("next page");
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I think I've got it.

I've added a **ref** to child component inside **App.vue** and callback on `<transition @enter="enterMethod>`- it triggers everytime on the next page at the start of reveal animation

This is the method attached to the callback on `<transition>`

```
enterMethod() {
     this.$refs.childComponent.someChildFunction()
}
```

**end result:**

```
<template>
    <ChildComponent ref="childComponent" />
    <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in" @enter="enterMethod>
            <component :is="Component"/>
        </transition>
    </router-view>
</template>

<script>
import { ChildComponent } from "./components";
export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
        ChildComponent ,
    },
    methods:{
       enterMethod() {
            this.$refs.childComponent.someChildFunction()
       }       
    }
};
</script>
```